# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, php7

Tengo un proyecto que en local me funciona perfecto, me muestra todos los datos como quiero y sin problemas. Cuando lo subí al servidor la mayoría de cosas me funcionan bien, a excepción de algo en específico y siempre me devuelve el mismo error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".
Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué pueda estar pasando esto? Les dejo mi código por si alguien logra ver lo que yo no...

Acá es donde mando a llamar el comentario que necesito:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function load_comment(inicio,fin,origen)
    {
        $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_comment.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{inicio:inicio,fin:fin,origen:origen},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#display_comment').html(data);
        }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Y este es el archivo del comentario:

```
<?php

include ("../bd/bd.php");

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

if(isset($_POST["inicio"], $_POST["fin"],$_POST["origen"]) )
{

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT date(fecha_encuesta) as fecha, respuesta,numero FROM tabla_comentarios  
  where DATE(fecha_encuesta) BETWEEN '".$_POST["inicio"]."'  AND '".$_POST["fin"]."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200");

  if ($_POST["origen"] =='todos')
  {   
    while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $respuesta=$profile['respuesta'];
      $numero=$profile['numero'];
      $fecha=$profile['fecha'];

      $response = $client->post('https://api.meaningcloud.com/sentiment-2.1', [
          'multipart' => [
              [
                  'name'     => 'key',
                  'contents' => 'MI_KEY'
              ],
              [
                  'name'     => 'txt',
                  'contents' => $respuesta            
              ],
              [
                  'name'     => 'lang',
                  'contents' => 'es'  # 2-letter code, like en es fr ...
              ]        
          ]
      ]);

      $status = $response->getStatusCode();
      $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true); 

        foreach($body["sentence_list"] as $row) 
        {
          $texto=$row['text'];
          $score=$row['score_tag'];

          if($score == 'P'|| $score == 'P+'){
            $pos="&#128512";
            $output= ' <div class="item">
            <label class="nombres">
            <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <br>
            <div class="panel-heading"><span class="numberCircle"> <font size=5>'.$pos.'</font></span> <b>'.$numero.'</b> - <i>'.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha)).'</i></div>
              <br>
              <div class="panel-body">'.$texto.'</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </label>
            ';
            echo $output;  
          } //if
        } //foreach
    } //while
  } //if

    

  elseif ($_POST["origen"] =='wabot')
  {
  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT date(fecha_encuesta) as fecha, respuesta,numero FROM tabla_comentarios  
  where DATE(fecha_encuesta) BETWEEN '".$_POST["inicio"]."' AND '".$_POST["fin"]."' and (origen ='WA' or origen ='Chatbot_WA') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200");

    while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
      {
        $respuesta=$profile['respuesta'];
        $numero=$profile['numero'];
        $fecha=$profile['fecha'];

        $response = $client->post('https://api.meaningcloud.com/sentiment-2.1', [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'key',
                    'contents' => 'MI_KEY'
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'txt',
                    'contents' => $respuesta            
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'lang',
                    'contents' => 'es'  # 2-letter code, like en es fr ...
                ]        
            ]
        ]);

        $status = $response->getStatusCode();
        $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true); 

          foreach($body["sentence_list"] as $row) 
          {
            $texto=$row['text'];
            $score=$row['score_tag'];

            if($score == 'P'|| $score == 'P+'){
              $pos="&#128512";
              $output= ' <div class="item">
              <label class="nombres">
              <div class="panel panel-default" >
              <br>
              <div class="panel-heading"><span class="numberCircle"> <font size=5>'.$pos.'</font></span> <b>'.$numero.'</b> - <i>'.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha)).'</i></div>
                <br>
                <div class="panel-body">'.$texto.'</div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </label>
              ';
              echo $output;    
            } //if
          } //foreach
      } //while
  } //elseif supremo
      



  else
  {
  $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT date(fecha_encuesta) as fecha, respuesta,numero FROM tabla_comentarios  
  where DATE(fecha_encuesta) BETWEEN '".$_POST["inicio"]."' AND '".$_POST["fin"]."' and origen ='".$_POST["origen"]."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200");

    while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
      {
        $respuesta=$profile['respuesta'];
        $numero=$profile['numero'];
        $fecha=$profile['fecha'];

        $response = $client->post('https://api.meaningcloud.com/sentiment-2.1', [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'key',
                  'contents' => 'MI_KEY'
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'txt',
                    'contents' => $respuesta            
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'lang',
                    'contents' => 'es'  # 2-letter code, like en es fr ...
                ]        
            ]
        ]);

        $status = $response->getStatusCode();
        $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true); 

          foreach($body["sentence_list"] as $row) 
          {
            $texto=$row['text'];
            $score=$row['score_tag'];

            if($score == 'P'|| $score == 'P+'){
              $pos="&#128512";
              $output= ' <div class="item">
              <label class="nombres">
              <div class="panel panel-default" >
              <br>
              <div class="panel-heading"><span class="numberCircle"> <font size=5>'.$pos.'</font></span> <b>'.$numero.'</b> - <i>'.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha)).'</i></div>
                <br>
                <div class="panel-body">'.$texto.'</div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </label>
              ';
              echo $output;   
            } //if
          } //foreach
      } //while
  } //else
} //if supremo
?>
```

Comment: Busca el log de errores en tu servidor, ahi se debería de estar el mensaje exacto indicando que falló

Comment: Si el log de errores no te muestra info detallada, mira en los errores de php (si no lo tienes configura un archivo log para php, en php.ini)